# liveness and readiness probe count

Tags: kubernetes

I had a doubt on the count shown inside the pod as liveness and readiness probe failures. Does the count increment for every failure OR does the count increment after the failureThreshold count is breached? Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

It counts increment for every failure. If the count passes the `failureThreshold` count then it restarts the pod according to the restarting policy and also depending the probes (differently for liveness and readiness probe). Kubernetes try a probe `failureThreshold` times then give up. For `liveness` probe it does restart the container and for `readiness` probe the Pod will be marked `Unready`.

Comment: When it restarts, will it try to wait for the currently processing request to end?

Comment: @venkatesh no, there will be no currently processing request as it was not ready/live. By `readiness` probe we see whether the pod is ready to serve the traffic, and by `liveness` probe we see whether the pod is alive. So, if these probes fails that means we didn't send traffic to that pod yet.

Comment: Thanks @sahadat. But i have a situation where the containers kept restarting. Thrice in an hour to be precise.  Pod stayed intact & the container was serving traffic.  So, in this context, i wish to understand whether it would have cut short any of the in-process requests

Comment: @venkatesh no there won't be any in-process requests when the container come back after restarting, by the way a traffic went to container through pod.

Answer (score 0):

When a pod starts and the probe fails, Kubernetes will try **failureThreshold** times before it give up. Giving up in case of a liveness probe means restarting the pod. In case of a readiness probe the pod will be marked Unready. **failureThreshold**- **Defaults** value is **3** and **Minimum** value is **1**.